# React Native Expo: Dropdown Button / Split Button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

How do I write the code to create a drop-up button like the picture below? 
I am only able to create 1 button, but not a split button at Adopt now and the down button that unhides the 2 other options/buttons.

I have tried reactstrap/react-bootstrap, but they were rather difficult to use and I kept getting a lot of errors. Are there other ways around it?

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this using React or React Native?

Comment: @MayconMesquita I am trying to use React Native.

Comment: Unfortunately, reactstrap and react-bootstrap don't work with React Native.

Comment: @MayconMesquita I see! Thank you for letting me know. Are there any ways I can replicate the above using React Native?

Comment: I would use react-native-modal-dropdown for that, works for RN Expo and is highly customizable. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [react-native-modal-dropdown](https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown), then apply some customizations (eg. change bg to yellow).

In [docs](https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown#props) you have 20+ props to change the style and component's behavior.

### Instalation

```
npm i react-native-modal-dropdown -save
```

### Usage

```
import ModalDropdown from 'react-native-modal-dropdown';
```

```js
<ModalDropdown
  defaultValue='Adopt now'
  options={['Foster me', 'Sponsor me']}
  textStyle={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
/>
```